# React Native status bar hidden doesn't work when navigating back to a screen (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar

I have used `<StatusBar hidden />` and I've also tried `StatusBar.setHidden(true)` both in componentWillMount() and in the render() methods and it works when I open a component for the first time. But if I navigate to another screen and then open the previous screen again, most of the times the status bar appears.

Is there any way to ensure the status bar is always hidden in every component?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.wixnav2;

import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.res.Configuration; 

public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
  intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
  this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Window window = getWindow();
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
     window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in your `onCreate` in your activity class

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }
```

if use SplashActivy you can use this code

```
Window window = getWindow();
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Problem is, i my MainActivity I'm not extending Activity, I'm extending SpalshActitvity because of wix navigation, So, I get an error if I try to add the onCreate. Any tips?

Comment: I'm getting lots of erros when trying to run this.. I'll edit my question with my mainActivity code if it helps.